# while creating dynamic stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

issue: unable to run , keep complains syntax error. Please advise.

Below is the stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS src.sp_load_staging_tables $$
CREATE PROCEDURE src.sp_load_staging_tables()
BEGIN
declare l_table char(30);
declare l_row_count int(10);

set l_table='customers';

set @s=concat('select count(*) into', l_row_count, 'from',l_table);

PREPARE dynamic_statement from @s;

EXECUTE dynamic_statement;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;

END $$
```

Comment: Please provide the exact syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the syntax error, but one thing that stands out like a sore thumb is that `@s` is going to contain the string:

```
select count(*) into0fromcustomers
```

And that's not a valid SQL statement.